# NullPointerException in the Netbeans tutorial for Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, netbeans-7, netbeans-6.9

I try to follow the [Netbeans e-commerce tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/intro.html) to familiarize myself with Netbeans. I use Netbeans 7.0, the tutorial is recommended for Netbeans 6.8-6.9. Usually the adaptations are quite easy (the displayed elements are in a different order, or there are more fields).

The tutorial states in the third chapter: "[Make sure that the 'Enable Contexts and Dependency Injection' option is deselected.](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/setup-dev-environ.html)"

For [chapter 7](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/entity-session.html), I adapt it according to what it says in chapter 7, especially adding the following code in `ControllerServlet`:

```
@EJB
private CategoryFacade categoryFacade;

public void init() throws ServletException {

    // store category list in servlet context
    getServletContext().setAttribute("categories", categoryFacade.findAll()); // line 37
}
```

I try to run it when they say to run it, and I receive a `NullPointerException` on line 37. Line 37 is the actual code in the init method written here above. The exception occurs on the server side, so I guess that at some point, the people who wrote the tutorial changed their mind and activated CDI. I tried to add a dummy `beans.xml` to fix the issue, without success.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

After this, I downloaded the code provided and redid the work from their "breakpoint" (file AffableBean_snapshot3.zip), I got the same `NullPointerException`. I also took the version of the project as it should be after this part of the tutorial (AffableBean_snapshot4.zip) and it still fails at the exact same point.

So, what am I doing wrong? Should I really use Netbeans 6.9 instead of 7.0? The only notable difference is the filename of some xml file that are `sun-*` in Netbeans 6.9 and `glassfish-*` in Netbeans 7.0.

Comment: Do you instanciate categoryFacade somewhere else ? If not, you can't avoid a nullPointerException on this line.

Comment: That's exactly my point. The tutorial seems to say everything is fine while NOT instanciating categoryFacade. It's annotated with @EJB, so CDI should take over and actually instanciate. But the tutorial says on purpose "hey guys, don't enable CDI". So there is absolutely something I must be missing, but I don't know what.